# garbage value in JSON file while storing the output

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, utf-8

while I was web scraping a site and storing the output, I observed my numerical data is getting replaced by some kind of gibberish data. I don't know what to do.

```
json.dumps(lst)
with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
json.dump(lst , f,indent=4)
```

this is how I was storing the data

```
[
{
    "product_title": "Skybags Brat Black 46 Cms Casual Backpack",
    "MRP": "\u20b92,010.00",
    "Discounted_price": "\u20b9969.00"
},
[
```

and this is I how the data looks like

UPDATE :

facing this error after adding `json.dumps(lst, ensure_ascii=False)` to my code

[image]

Comment: Not an expert but this looks like character encoding

Comment: yes, I think so any solution?

Comment: A quick fix would be to strip the unicode characters out before writing the json file, i.e. ```json.dumps(lst, ensure_ascii=False).encode('ascii', 'ignore')```

Comment: nicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u20b9' in position 1: character maps to <undefined>  facing this error after applying above code to my script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not gibberish. It's a Unicode character. You can use `ensure_ascii=False` in `json.dumps()`

```
import json
l = [
{
    "product_title": "Skybags Brat Black 46 Cms Casual Backpack",
    "MRP": "\u20b92,010.00",
    "Discounted_price": "\u20b9969.00"
    }
]

x = json.loads(json.dumps(l, ensure_ascii=False))
print(x)
```

```
[
{
'product_title': 'Skybags Brat Black 46 Cms Casual Backpack',
 'MRP': '₹2,010.00', 
'Discounted_price': '₹969.00'
}
]
```

To write the data as is to a file. Use this

```
with open('data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(lst , f,indent=4,ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: I'm repeating the same thing again n again first of all I'm writing to the file not reading it and still facing the issue nicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u20b9' in position 1: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: You did not use ```encoding='utf-8'``` in ```open()```. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

that because the json.dump always read as ensure ascii
You can change `json.dump(lst , f,indent=4)` to `json.dump(lst , f,indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)`